# How to add a dynamic class to magento 2 page-header based on a configuration value without using js

Tags: header

[image: Default Magento Header]

i want to add a class (black-theme) after the page-header like in the image shown below
Note: i have already tried to add class using JavaScript but its causing a slight delay in applying the class. please help

[image: We need the header like this with additional class (blask]

Comment: Can you describe your requirements in more detail?